# Creating nodes with dynamic number of input sockets?

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on, pynodes

Is it possible in any way to create one's own node type in one of the node editors (let's just say the Compositor for example) that can have a dynamic number of inputs?  Not a group node, just a regular node?

For my use case, I would like to be able to do one of two things:

1. Have multiple inputs come into a single socket of a given type (I know this is not possible and probably never will be).
2. Dynamically add another input socket of a particular type if an input is attached to a socket of that type.  The output file node has that functionality [implemented in C here](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender/blob/9f8bb5813bbbd2fc8a6a174b8ff4d86529bef94a/source/blender/nodes/composite/nodes/node_composite_outputFile.c#L106), but similar functionality for adding sockets dynamically to a node does not seem to be present for any other node type or accessible via the python API.

Is what I am requesting simply not possible in Blender at present?

Comment: I would think that creating a node group to do what you want would be the easiest way to go about adding a custom node (I know you want to avoid this, but I don't see why). What kind if node are you trying to add?

Comment: Essentially, I'm investigating whether blender's node editor can fulfill some requirements for porting a custom (in-house) visual programming environment that couples some image processing concepts with some scientific computing concepts.  The existing environment essentially allows the equivalent of multiple noodles to connect at a single socket (case 1 above), but could be emulated most easily by dynamically adding sockets of a given type as in case 2 above.  Forcing our users to construct group nodes to emulate existing behavior adds too many manual steps to keep the workflow user-friendly.